# Тег Audio в Safari. Почему не работает код?

Tags: html, html5, safari, аудио

Не могли бы вы прояснить, почему данный код не работает в браузере Safari:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="/catcher.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="/catcher.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Вроде бы нужный кодек подключен, но музыка не воспроизводится.

Что не так, скажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: потому-что ваш сафари под виндой :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, это верно! А, скажем под IOS заработало бы?

Comment: Куда же все так внезапно пропали???

Answer (score 2):

Должен поддерживать. Попробуйте в **type** [указать нужный кодек](http://htmlbook.ru/html/source/type)

Comment: Не помогло...перебрал все MIME-Типы c аудиокодеками...

Answer (score -2):

Не надо ставить `/` перед `catcher.mp3` или `catcher.ogg`. `/` используют, когда надо показать путь к файлу, например `<source src="audio/catcher.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />`

Comment: а если они лежат в корне?.. не нужно путать людей.

Comment: Изменил ответ, вот

Comment: Это все равно не решает вопроса. Данный код не работает только в сафари. Это значит что в Хроме, Мозилле и пр. он работает. Это значит что ссылки на файлы указаны корректно и они доступны. Более того относительные ссылки никогда не были предпочтительными. Их стоит использовать только в том случае, когда расположение ресурсов привязано к расположению html файла, что является крайне редким кейсом.

Comment: Некропостинг детектед)